# IAP won't load into UItableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, in-app-purchase

I have been messing with this issue for several days. I am attempting to get my IAP to load from iTunes. I do not get any errors when attempting to load (i.e. product id not found). I have filled out my taxes and agreements. I just don't understand why it will not load. So I have attached my code that should load that. If you need any other parts of it just let me know (this code worked before the update).

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
import Foundation

class NewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ProductTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.tableView.delegate = self as? UITableViewDelegate
        self.tableView.dataSource = self as? UITableViewDataSource
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        //Hide all lines
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: CGSize.init(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 0.0001)))

        //First thing we need to show the product which we loaded from iTunes connect in order for us to buy it
        //In the previous video we used post notification whenever the products are done loading from the server
        //Let's add an observer so we get notifed whenever the products get loaded

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.SKProductsDidLoadFromiTunes), name: NSNotification.Name.init("SKProductsHaveLoaded"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.SKProductsDidLoadFromiTunes), name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "ReceiptDidUpdated"), object: nil)

        //We need also to call the function anyway when the view did load in case the products got loaded before our oberver is added
        SKProductsDidLoadFromiTunes()
    }

    @objc func StoreManagerDidPurchaseautosubscriptions(notification:Notification){
        guard ((notification.userInfo?["id"]) != nil) else {
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    //Since this function already update our UI. Let's use it for our receiptDidUpdated
    @objc func SKProductsDidLoadFromiTunes(){
        //Now we need to update the table since we have the products ready
        //We need to use the main thread when updating the UI
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.isHidden = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    //Selector from cell button (Unlock button)
    func didTapCellButton(sender:CustomButton){
        let index = sender.index
        let product = StoreManager.shared.productsFromStore[index!.row]

        StoreManager.shared.buy(product: product)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code that actually attempts to query your IAP products?

Comment: i will post later im currently at work but would that be the manager for the app store?